# How do I add an administrator password requirement to edit this batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is the code I have to hide a folder. Unfortunately I have friends that can't leave my stuff alone e.g. school projects, family photos and so on. So with the help of the internet i setup this batch file to keep my friends away. The problem is that they aren't that stupid, so they would probably find out the password by clicking "edit". So I was hoping i could get help with setting up administrator password requirement to edit the file.

```
cls 
@ECHO OFF 
title Folder Private 
if EXIST "HTG Locker" goto UNLOCK 
if NOT EXIST Private goto MDLOCKER 
:CONFIRM 
echo Are you sure you want to lock the folder(Y/N) 
set/p "cho=>" 
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==n goto END 
if %cho%==N goto END 
echo Invalid choice. 
goto CONFIRM 
:LOCK 
ren Private "HTG Locker" 
attrib +h +s "HTG Locker" 
echo Folder locked 
goto End 
:UNLOCK 
echo Enter password to unlock folder 
set/p "pass=>" 
if NOT %pass%== Password goto FAIL 
attrib -h -s "HTG Locker" 
ren "HTG Locker" Private 
echo Folder Unlocked successfully 
goto End 
:FAIL 
echo Invalid password 
goto end 
:MDLOCKER 
md Private 
echo Private created successfully 
goto End 
:End
```

By the way, I am new with coding so I don't understand half of this code :Þ

Comment: Well, those people are not quite your closest friends, are they?

Comment: Lock your computer when beeing away ;)

Answer (score 1):

try to put something like this where you need the password of your script:

```
runas /user:domain\username "cmd /c rem"
if errorlevel 1  (
  echo invalid password
  exit /b 666
) else (
   attrib -h -s "HTG Locker"
)
```

or even better :

```
 runas /user:domain\username "cmd /c attrib -h -s \"HTG Locker\""
```

more for [RUNAS](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html)

Answer (score 0):

I do not really answer your question, but you can use bat to exe converter from here: 
http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php
This way, your friends cannot edit your script.

EDIT: to hide a folder you can just use cmd, it takes only one command:

```
attrib +H path\to\folder
```